# Magento admin access

Tags: admin-panel

I have Magento website, and its working fine

But some conflagration happened in the server so when I tried to access **Magento admin** but it gives me the **page not found**, the system admin said the some admin table does not exist it seems have been deleted such as core_  tables, but the website still working fine. any help??

Comment: Check what is admin path in local.xml and try to open with www.domain.com/index.php/admin

Comment: there is no such table like core_ tables in magento